# How to display user's name ("Last, First" (sn, givenname) or "Common" (cn)) instead of their user name (uid) in the list of user accounts?

Tags: phpldapadmin

When I login to phpLDAPadmin, the list of users on the left are listed by their `uid` attribute, for example:
⭐ Create new entry here
 `uid=<uid1>`
 `uid=<uid2>`
[...]
 `uid=<uidN>`
⭐ Create new entry here

I would like it to use a different attribute, for example the user's "Common Name" which is typically a combination of their first (given) and last (sur) names:
 `cn=<cn1>`

or maybe better to sort by last name, for example:
 `sn=<sn1>, givenname=<givenname1>`

It's not really necessary to include the name of the attribute, can those be left out so something like this is shown instead?
 `<sn1>, <givenname1>`

Thanks!

Searched the docs, the phpLDAPadmin interface, Github issues and discussions, and here on Stack Overflow for these options, was expecting to find the setting that controls what is displayed, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I first made a copy of `/etc/phpldapadmin/templates/creation/{your template_file}`. After that I edited it and changed the part: `<rdn>whatever you need</rdn>`

for example in `<rdn>cn</rdn>`.

All new objects are then displayed with the common name.

Comment: Thanks, that's one piece, but we have many users, so "sn, givenName" would be best.  That didn't seem to be the correct way to define it since it now shows up at the bottom of the new user template as "sn, givenName rdn" and the tool tip says "This attribute is not defined by the LDAP schema".  Once we have that correctly defined, we'd have to go back and edit every account's rdn value? just to display all current accounts by lastname?  So it's independent from phpLDAPadmin.  Ig it'd be better if there was just a way to have PLA display the accounts using "sn, givenName" instead of "rdn"...